# Apostrophies doesn't appear in my textfield

Tags: flash, text, apostrophe

I'm using some action script 3 to put some text in a texfield. Everything is alright, except that all the apostrohpies doesn't show up.

Here is my code:

```
_descriptionTXT.text = _source.description;
```

Insted of displaying 'I'm a description', it will show 'Im a description'

I check that the texte that I'm trying to put in textfield does have apostrophie and, yes, the texte inside `_source.description` really is 'I'm a description'.

I checked with flash develop by putting a break point, but if y try to trace the text, it replace the apostrophies with spaces?????????????

What is going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will have to hazard a guess that you are populating a input textfield and not a dynamic textfield? You need to make sure all fonts used are embedded if they are going to be used with input textfields. Many questions like this have been answered before: http://flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=9411. Hope this helps you out.